# Attributing the hold reason when the votes don't agree

Tags: support, closed-questions

When a question is closed, but those who voted on the closure don't agree on the reason, how does the site choose which reason to use in the attribution?

For example, I voted to close [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31327109/what-data-structures-will-you-use-to-implement-a-text-editor?lq=1) as a duplicate, and I provided  links to identical questions.  I was the third vote, so I know someone else voted to close because it was opinion-based and another said it was off-topic.

When attributing the close reason, the site says something like:

> put on hold as primarily opinion-based by Amit, NG., Adrian McCarthy, Romasz, Soner Gönül....

**Did it say "opinion-based" because that was the first vote, the last vote, the most popular vote, or is there some other scheme?**

I'm sometimes (mildly) annoyed to see my name attributed to a closure for a reason I don't agree with.  If I knew what scheme the site uses, I might be able to avoid some of these situations.

(Yes, in this case, opinion-based is arguably a valid reason.  My intent here is not to debate whether the site is doing something reasonable or whether this particular question was closed for the right reason.  I'm merely trying to understand the algorithm for attributions and to perhaps learn the rationale behind why it was chosen, so that I can then adjust my behavior to avoid being occasionally misrepresented.)

Comment: Wait, you said it was a dupe?   A dupe of what?  Let me know so that I can get my blowtorch out.

Comment: Everything I have seen makes me believe it is the highest voted reason but that is just from observation.

Comment: [What happens if a fifth person chooses a different reason to close?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/32700/165773)

Comment: Thanks @gnat.  There's good info there.

Comment: @Makoto:  What are you talking about?

Comment: You said it was a dupe.  I'm struggling to believe that this particular question is suitable for the site at all (as it's too broad in scope), and anything that's a duplicate of it should also be closed.

Comment: @Makoto:  I don't think I agree that this question is too broad.  There are several general questions about what data structure to use for a text editor on the site, and I listed some of them in the comments on the question.  Many of those are written better (or were written when the SO rules were laxer) but aren't much more specific than the one in question here.

Comment: Okay, I see what's going on.  You believed that the question in question was a duplicate of what you had linked to, but it really isn't; those other questions are better formed and more objective than the one we're discussing.  Nevermind me, then.

Comment: Binding votes (OP/gold badge dupe-hammer/mod) come first. Then it goes to majority.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54917/distinguish-close-votes-by-reason